# JS code involving modernizr not working the way it should?

Tags: javascript, modernizr

In an attempt to understand modernizr I ran the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script>
var yes = "yes";
var no = "no";
</script>

<script>
if (Modernizr.audio) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = yes;
}

else{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = no;
}
</script>

</head><body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body></html>
```

If the browser I run this code in does support audio (which it does) it should display "yes" but it displays nothing but a blank page. this is the the first time I used modernizr so bear with me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When the inline script is run, the `#demo` element is not loaded yet and therefore does not exist. Move the script below the element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  var yes = "yes";
  var no = "no";
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  if (Modernizr.audio) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = yes;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = no;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are trying to set `innerHTML` of your `p` element, but before `DOM load`.

You need to wrap your script in an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script>
var yes = "yes";
var no = "no";
</script>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  if (Modernizr.audio) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = yes;
  }

  else{
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = no;
  }
});
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

`DOMContentLoaded` ensures that the `DOM` (Document Object Model) has fully loaded so you can query elements within the `DOM`.

Or, as Patrick said, move the `script` to the end of the `body`

**FYI** This problem is caused by your implementation of `Javascript` not `Modernizer`

Comment: the extra line you added in the script is it used when you dont want to move the script below the element? how is your answer dufferent from patrick

Comment: Functionally, they both do the same job. The only difference is that you can declare mine before the HTML code, best practice is to follow Patricks answer and put your JS at the bottom of your HTML (before the closing `body` tag). That way, the HTML has already loaded so your JS has access to the elements.